# "#{serviceCatalogueController.allMap[category.key]}": Property 'key' not found on type java.util.HashMap$KeySet

Tags: jsf, primefaces, hashmap, el, datalist

I am trying to populate a map with values from inputText and inputTextArea. Also Date. In the backbean I have a map of like Map>

Basically, a Category can have many Attributes. These Attributes are input fields. For multiselect, dropdown and single select all i need is to set the attribute. But for TextArea, textField and Date I need to set the attribute plus the value which is why I have the String.

my jsf looks like

```
              <p:dataList id="serviceCatalogueCriteria" var="category" value="#{serviceCatalogueController.allMap.keySet()}">
                    <div id="categoryDiv" style="overflow: hidden;">
                        <div class="category-header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{serviceCatalogueController.allMap[category.key]}" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <!-- Text field, text area or date -->
                            <div class="category-text">
                                <ui:fragment
                                    rendered="#{categoryService.isTextField(category) or categoryService.isTextArea(category) or categoryService.isDate(category)}">
                                    <ui:fragment
                                        rendered="#{categoryService.isTextField(category)}">
                                        <p:dataList var="attribute" value="#{category.entrySet()}" >
                                            <p:inputText 
                                                value="#{category[attribute.key]}" />
                                        </p:dataList>
                                    </ui:fragment>
                                    <ui:fragment
                                        rendered="#{categoryService.isTextArea(category)}">
                                        <p:dataList var="attribute" value="#{category.entrySet()}" >
                                            <p:inputTextarea rows="3" cols="70"
                                                value="#{category[attribute.key]}"/>
                                        </p:dataList>
                                    </ui:fragment>
                                    <ui:fragment rendered="#{categoryService.isDate(category)}">
                                        <p:dataList var="attribute" value="#{category.entrySet()}" >
                                            <p:calendar
                                                value="#{category[attribute.key]}"
                                                showOn="button">
                                            </p:calendar>
                                        </p:dataList>
                                    </ui:fragment>
                                </ui:fragment>
                            </div>
                    <p:separator />
                </p:dataList>
```

And my back bean looks like

```
private Map<Category,Map<Attribute,String>> allMap;
//setter and getter
```

The error I get is

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /resources/PWAssessment/ServiceCatalogueFilters.xhtml @24,84 value="#{serviceCatalogueController.allMap[category.key]}": Property 'key' not found on type java.util.HashMap$KeySet
```

Why would this not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes.

1. `<p:dataList>` can't iterate over a `Set<E>` (nor `Map<K, V>`). It can only iterate over `List<E>` or `E[]` or `DataModel<E>`.
2. Even if it would have worked, the `var="category"` represents the `Category` instance itself, not some `Map`. If the `<p:dataList>` would have supported `Set<E>`, you should just have used

   ```
   <h:outputText value="#{serviceCatalogueController.allMap[category]}" />
   ```

   And, equivalently, further in the code, the `#{category.entrySet()}` wouldn't have worked either, as the `#{category}` would represent the `Category` instance itself.

The `<p:dataList>` supports iterating over an array. So, this should do:

```
<p:dataList value="#{serviceCatalogueController.allMap.entrySet().toArray()}" var="categoryEntry">
    This is Category: #{categoryEntry.key}
    This is Map&lt;Attribute,String&gt;: #{categoryEntry.value}
    ...
    <p:dataList value="#{categoryEntry.value.entrySet().toArray()}" var="attributeEntry">
        This is Attribute: #{attributeEntry.key}
        This is String: #{attributeEntry.value}
```

This is quite inefficient though. I strongly recommend to remodel the model as such that you just have something like a `List<CategoryDTO>`. Otherwise, grab `<c:forEach>` which supports efficiently iterating over a `Map`:

```
<c:forEach items="#{serviceCatalogueController.allMap}" var="categoryEntry">
    This is Category: #{categoryEntry.key}
    This is Map&lt;Attribute,String&gt;: #{categoryEntry.value}
    ...
    <c:forEach items="#{categoryEntry.value}" var="attributeEntry">
        This is Attribute: #{attributeEntry.key}
        This is String: #{attributeEntry.value}
```

Comment: Hi! I have come alone but hit another wall. I implemented the forEach as you suggested. Works like a charm with Maps. However, I got to the point where im dealing with dropdownlist. I need to now display Attributes in the dropdown list. In addition to the previous textArea, textField and Date. I cant seem to get p:selectOneMenu along with f:selectItems to populate my drop down list. Can you help me with this? I read somewhere where it says i cant use this inside forEach. This would be a bummer. @BalusC

Comment: You mean, you want to use `<f:selectItems>` on `Set<Attribute>` of each category? Then just use `<f:selectItems value="#{categoryEntry.value.keySet()}">`. For future new questions, please press "Ask Question" button. The current one is answered and you shouldn't ask new questions in comments section.

Comment: great thank you. ill put a little more thought on this @BalusC